# Looping over each line of file and summing fields

Tags: bash

So I have a .csv file which contains data in the format below:

```
ID, text, value_1, value_2, value 3
1, abc, 10, 20, 30
2, def, 40, 50, 60
3, ghi, 70, 80, 90
```

I am trying to code a shell script so that it will take each line and assign a value to each variable value_1, value_2 and value_3 and then sum those into a total variable. The idea is so that I can find the top 10 lines in the file that have the highest totals.

For example the total variable for line 1 would be 60.

I've outlined the pseudocode for the problem, but I am having trouble assigning the values in each field to the variables.

```
# !/ bin/bash

# NUM_VALUE_1=0
# NUM_VALUE_2=0
# NUM_VALUE_3=0
# TOTAL=0
# HIGHEST=()

# for line in $(selecting fields 3, 4, 5); do
#    NUM_VALUE_1 = $line(f3)
#    NUM_VALUE_2 = $line(f4)
#    NUM_VALUE_3 = $line(f5)
#
#    TOTAL = NUM_VALUE_1 + NUM_VALUE_2 + NUM_VALUE_3
#
#    Keep line if total is in the top 10 highest values
# done
#
# print the top 10 lines
```

Code I am working on:

```
NUM_VALUE_1=0
NUM_VALUE_2=0
NUM_VALUE_3=0
TOP_10=()

for line in $(tail -n +2 data.csv | cut -d, -f3,4,5); do 

    NUM_VALUE_1="echo $line | cut -d, -f1"
    NUM_VALUE_2="echo $line | cut -d, -f2"
    NUM_VALUE_3="echo $line | cut -d, -f3"

    $TOTAL=$((NUM_VALUE_1 + NUM_VALUE_2 + NUM_VALUE_3))

    #keep only if its in the highest 10
done
```

I'm only new to bash so have tried a lot of variations and haven't got very far. I think I'll be able to sort the 10 highest once I can find out how to assign the field to the variables that is the part I am most stuck with.

Comment: _csv_ file is separated by comma. You have a table. With `|` as a some graphical sign. And it looks as the output of `mysql`, right?

Comment: Sorry you're right it is a csv file, I just put the values in table format to make it easier to view.

Comment: [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).  Remember to set `IFS=,`

Comment: We haven't covered IFS yet so I would prefer if I were able to complete this with what I have learnt so far. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Pufff, ok. 1. Its' `TOTAL=` not `$TOTAL=`. The `$` is not in front in assignment. 2. Add all to the `TOP_10+=("$TOTAL")`. After all sums are added, you can sort the array. Print the array with just `printf "%s\n"` and then call `sort -n`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not going for a more straight-forward solution rather than using for loop, i.e.

```
echo ID, text, value_1, value_2, value_3 > /tmp/mio.csv
echo 1, abc, 10, 20, 30 >> /tmp/mio.csv
echo 2, def, 40, 50, 60 >> /tmp/mio.csv
echo 3, ghi, 70, 80, 90 >> /tmp/mio.csv

tail -n +2 /tmp/mio.csv | awk '{ SUM = $3+$4+$5 } { print SUM , ",",  $0 }' | sort -n -k 1 | tail -n 10

#Eventually you can chain a cut to purge the totalization column
```